# Bootstrap DropDown not loading

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

Using an example of W3Schools at the following :[W3Schools DropDown](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_dropdown&stacked=h)

I have followed the example but it is not working for me. Here's where I want it:

```
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" @Html.ActionLink("Our Church", "Index", "Home")</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">MTB Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">MTB Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">MTB Link 3</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                        <li><a href="#">MTB Link 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">MTB Link 5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

I honestly don't understand why this isn't working. My css file contains the correct code.

Comment: is it not showing at all or what isn't working?

Comment: @Koosh it comes up with the name on nav bar, but when I click it, nothing appears